# Breadcrumb in List and Libraries WebPart

Tags: list, web-part

Is there a way to enable breadcrumb for a list webpart? I am talking about the OOB webpart where you can view all the folders and documents of a list within a webpart.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using 2010 with the large library support enabled, you have the ability to filter dynamically from meta categories to the left. It's not a true breadcrumb, but makes things much easier than returning to the top level to start over.

In general, weight the options of folders vs. meta data. In the vast majority of cases, you can replicate the appearance of "folders" by using views derived from meta data and vastly improve the user experience. Many people fall into the pitfall of managing a document library like a LAN share/file system.

To my knowledge there isn't any OOTB breadcrumb like control capability for 2007, and even my suggestion above for 2010 isn't truly what you're looking for. You'd need to cook up a custom control to achieve this I believe.

Comment: No, that's not what i am looking for. If you are in the homepage of your site (default.aspx), you have a option of adding a list/doc lib webpart. I want the breadcrumb functionality within the webpart.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You should see breadcrumbs by default if you're on AllItems.aspx. Is that not what you're looking at?

Comment: I think he's looking for breadcrumbs through the folders of a document library, not site navigation. At least that's the way I interpreted it.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it, without writing your own version of the ListView web part.

The List View web part is showing you a view onto your library, but you're not actually there. From the point of view of SharePoint's navigation you are still at the location of the page with the ListView on it; this remains true even as you 'navigate' down through the folders. So all the standard navigation elements won't work (even if you could somehow add them to your web part)

Answer (score 0):

Nope, that's not OOTB functionality. You'll have to write something to achieve what you want.